# Add Comma After "official" in "official third-party documentation"?

Tags: technical-writing, grammar

I'm drafting an internal standard on internal documentation covering third-party products or services in [my organization](https://www.daveramsey.com/).

> Documentation covering third-party products or services SHOULD NOT:
>
> - Include specific details or information already covered in official third-party documentation—to avoid plagiarism or the spread of misinformation when official third-party documentation is updated and internal documentation is not

One of my team members submitted an edit to change:

```
official third-party documentation
```

To:

```
official, third-party documentation
```

I disagreed with him—my argument being that "official" in this context is an adjective and adding a comma would change the meaning.

Should I add a comma after the word "official" in "official third-party documentation"?

Comment: Is it the third party or the documentation that is official?

Comment: @PTm In this case, I think the documentation is "official". For example: AWS is the third-party and AWS Documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/index.html) is the official documentation for the AWS third-party service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two adjectives in this phrase that modify the word documentation: official and third-party. If they are coordinating adjectives, a comma is required. If they are cumulative adjectives, no comma is necessary.

There are two tests to determine if adjectives before a noun are coordinating adjectives:

1. Can you replace such a comma with the coordinating conjunction "and"?
2. Can you flip the adjectives without altering the meaning?

In this case, "third-party, official documentation" doesn't work. It suggests that third-party documentation is its own thing, like fire truck or Christmas tree. The adjectives are, then, cumulative adjectives, and no comma is required (see [Commas with Adjectives](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/commas-with-adjectives)).

Comment: Everything @Thom Chittom said, but additionally, I would add this link to a reference of the order of adjectives in the English language: https://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/adjectives/order-of-adjectives/
I know of other languages that actually don't have this restriction, but for English it matters.

In conjunction with Thom's response as well as the order of adjectives reference, I would call `official` a #2 type adjective (Quality or opinion) and `third‑party` a # 7 adjective (Proper adjective).

Comment: I very much like the addition in your article of why commas or conjunctions occur when multiple adjectives are modifying a noun. Thank you for sharing.